# time command do not work for my shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, time

I try to measure the time of my shell script (I normally run it with `./my-script`)  with `time` linux command like this:

```
time my-script
```

but I receive the following error

> -bash: my-script: command not found

This approach I took it from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314382, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Use the full path? `/usr/bin/time /path/to/my-script` to be sure.

Comment: it worked with the full path to my-script. thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you normally run the script as `./my-script`, then you should run it with `time` using `time ./my-script` as well.

The reason is that `time` doesn't change the way your `PATH` is searched and you need to give a path name (relative or absolute), rather than just a naked command to run, since the current directory is typically not in your `PATH`.